# Finding the maximum of function in loop javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to optimize one function. Ideas appreciated.

Function is regular while loop, that calls another function with incremented parameter

```
var q= 0, 
   a = getA(q),
   b = getB(q);

while (a<b) {

   q += 1;

   a = getA(q);
   b = getB(q);
}
```

The problem is that getA and getB functions are pretty heavy, so I want to minimize number of loops.
It can be achieved by setting several loops - one with 1000 increment, second with 100, next with 10 and last one with 1 increment, but this solution still ugly.

**Can the task be done in one loop with less loops then q?**

Comment: Is the problem that the browsers shows you an alert because it's too long ? Not sure to be able to give you an answer without the code of `getA` and `getB`.

Comment: In some cases i have more then 10 000 loops involved. One takes just about 12 msec, but all of them...users feel that

Comment: getA and getB are pretty complicated functions, and have nothing to do with the task - reducing number of loops. I'm trying to figure out how to increment q not just by 1, but with some multiplier and reduce multipler when a gets > then b

Comment: Your focus should be on making `getA` and `getB` faster. Caching would help if you do this more than once, otherwise your approach to reduce the number of calls is the only way, and it could easily be ugly.

Comment: We can't do magic and reduce 10000 to a shortest number. You have to think about the global process, not just about one loop. That's why I ask you for `getA` and `getB`

Comment: sadly there is no way to optimize getA and getB - https://tradernet.ru/data/blogs/posts/13939_1.png

Comment: i'm just sure that there is simple and basic way to increment q with multipler in the same loop - the same I do in four loops

Comment: first we have to find q with preicsion say 100 000, then with precision 10 000, then with 1000, then 100, 10 and finaly with precision 1

For example if answer is 99 000, simple approach with increment of 1 will take 99 000 loops, but five loops with different increments will take just ~90 loops

Comment: Maybe, maybe not, but there is no way I can help you without more details. EDIT : You're talking about the "binary search algorithm".

Comment: Presumably the result of *getA* and *getB* converges for some value of *q*. Therefore you need to analyse the result of some value of `q` and `q+x` to work out some value of x that is close to where they converge.

Comment: "Therefore you need to analyse the result of some value of q and q+x to work out some value of x that is close to where they converge."

Those functions are not linear, so I'cant make a guess based on results for some q

Comment: Keep multiplying `q` by `2` until `b >= a`, then do `q = q/2; r = q + (q = q/2)` and test again, now you know which side of `r` to look at and keep doing `+` or `-` `q = q/2` ;) stop when `q = 1`

Comment: multipling by 2 is a good idea, but it shortens number of loops just twice. I want the multiplier (in your suggestion 2) be one of the variables and it should start from 100 000

Comment: @ProstoTrader the number of iterations is more important than the number of loops you have. My suggestion makes the number of iterations exponentially smaller compared to a linear search

Comment: by number of loops i've meant number of iterations, sorry